# Does mocha have a testing live mode?

Tags: mocha.js

I am doing TDD with mocha and chai to test some NodeJS scripts, and I have to run "mocha" every time that I want to run the test again.

Is there a way to setup mocha and chai to run the test just after I save the source file? like an option "mocha -–live-reload" (that is just an example...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs, the --watch flag should do this.